# Boost mutex locking on same thread

Tags: c++, boost, lua, mutex

I'm new to the boost library, and it's such an amazing library! Also, I am new to mutexes, so forgive me if I am making a newbie mistake.

Anyway, I have two functions called `FunctionOne` and `FunctionTwo`. `FunctionOne` and `FunctionTwo` are called asynchronously by a different thread. So here's what happens: In `FunctionOne`, I lock a global mutex at the beginning of the function and unlock the global mutex at the end of the function. Same thing for `FunctionTwo`.

Now here's the problem: at times, `FunctionOne` and `FunctionTwo` are called less than a few milliseconds apart (not always though). So, `FunctionOne` begins to execute and half-way through `FunctionTwo` executes. When `FunctionTwo`  locks the mutex, the entire thread that `FunctionOne` and `FunctionTwo` are on is stopped, so `FunctionOne` is stuck half-way through and the thread waits on itself in `FunctionTwo` forever. So, to summarize:

- Function 1 locks mutex and begins executing code.
- Function 2 is called a few ms later and locks the mutex, freezing the thread func 1 and 2 are on.
- Now func 1 is stuck half-way through and the thread is frozen, so func 1 never finishes and the mutex is locked forever, waiting for func 1 to finish.

What does one do in such situations? Here is my code:

```
boost::mutex g_Mutex;
lua_State* L;

// Function 1 is called from some other thread
void FunctionOne()
{
    g_Mutex.lock();

    lua_performcalc(L);

    g_Mutex.unlock();
}

// Function 2 is called from some other thread a few ms later, freezing the thread
// and Function 1 never finishes
void FunctionTwo()
{
    g_Mutex.lock();

    lua_performothercalc(L);

    g_Mutex.unlock();
}
```

Comment: If f1 and f2 are invoked by the same thread, then how f2 can be called while f1 is still in progress? Do you mean f2 is called from f1?

Comment: That's what I'm confused about. I know for sure that FunctionOne and FunctionTwo are called from a separate thread. However, I did the following: `printf("Function: %s, time: %f", __FUNCTION__, globals->currentTime());` and at times both functions are called at once (and the application crashes for writing to the same resource), and with a mutex, the application waits on its own thread.

Comment: -1 The question needs a SSCCE. See http://www.sscce.org/ As is you're wasting your own time, but also ours. **Update** Hmmm. Why are old questions in the RSS feed?

Comment: I am curious, did you ever get down to the bottom of this issue?  It seems your description of the problem violated the principle of 'mutexes' in the first place...

Answer (score 8):

Are these functions intended to be re-entrant, such that FunctionOne will call itself or FunctionTwo while holding the mutex? Or vice versa, with FunctionTwo locking the mutex and then calling FunctionOne/FunctionTwo while the mutex is locked?

- If not, then you should not be calling these two functions from the same thread. If you intend FunctionTwo to block until FunctionOne has completed then it is a mistake to have it called on the same thread. That would happen if lua_performcalc ends up calling FunctionTwo. That'd be the only way they could be called on the same thread.
- If so, then you need a [recursive_mutex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.mutex_types.recursive_mutex). A regular mutex can only be locked once; locking it again from the same thread is an error. A recursive mutex can be locked multiple times by a single thread and is locked until the thread calls unlock an equal number of times.

In either case, you should avoid calling lock and unlock explicitly. If an exception is thrown the mutex won't get unlocked. It's better to use RAII-style locking, like so:

```
{
    boost::recursive_mutex::scoped_lock lock(mutex);

    ...critical section code...

    // mutex is unlocked when 'lock' goes out of scope
}
```

Comment: Even if re-entrant calling is required, you can avoid having recursive mutex.

Comment: The two functions are guaranteed to never call each other or itself, but both functions use the same resource and subroutines (e.g. lua_getglobal, lua_gettop, etc). When I logged the time that FunctionOne and FunctionTwo are run, they are called by different threads at the same time (to the 8th decimal place), in which the thread hangs forever. Sometimes the functions are called a few ms apart, and then there's no problem (usually, unless the time difference is small). I do not think two functions can execute at the same time on the same thread, so I am at a loss why this is happening.

Answer (score 3):

your description is incorrect. a mutex cannot be locked twice. you have a different problem.

- check for reentrance while the mutex is locked.
- check for exceptions

to avoid problems with exceptions you should use `boost::mutex::scoped_lock` ([RAAI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization))

Comment: With a scoped_lock, the waiting problem is gone, but now the two functions seem to be writing to the same resource at once. Obviously there is something I am not understanding. :(

Comment: if scoped_lock did resolve the deadlock, then 'lua_performcalc(L);' is probably throwing.

Comment: When I logged the time, sometimes FunctionOne and FunctionTwo fire at the exact same time (to the 8th decimal place) and lua_performcalc and lua_performothercalc try to write to the same resource and crash. Sometimes when they are a few ms apart, they crash as well. Only when the two functions are several hundred ms apart, they don't crash. When I use `g_Mutex.lock()` instead, the thread hangs on itself. I thought two functions can't execute at once on the same thread, so I do not know why this is happening.

Comment: Just found out that the thread freezes with a scoped lock as well... :(

Comment: do you have other mutexes or resource requests that might create a deadlock? (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock)

Comment: There's just 1 global mutex and multiple `lua_State* L;` stored in a std::vector like so: `std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<lua_State>> luaStateVector;` Both function 1 and function 2 iterate through this vector utilizing all the resources. Problem is, when both of these functions are called at the exact same time, the application crashes. If I prevent FunctionOne or FunctionTwo from ever firing, then no crash results. Neither FunctionOne or FunctionTwo use any other resource-- both functions try to access and write to the same resource.

Comment: Also, if I remove the bit of code that accesses the resource, then both functions are able to fire around the same time with no crashes. The result is the same even with a single `lua_State* L` without any vector. So, I don't think it's a deadlock as both functions utilize the same resource and don't rely on any other resources...

Comment: that is news. you did not post the necessary code. now the guess is: someone outside the functions is manipulating the data L is pointing to or the calc functions use other global data that is corrupted outside

Comment: what is the resource both functions go for? something that has to be requested and returned? then again, like for the mutex, RAAI! otherwise, especially in case of exceptions, you may 'forget' to return the resource.

Comment: *RAII? And I strongly concur. The question needs a SSCCE. The given code is simply not enough